# How do I style the TOC in a beamer template?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, templates

I'm making a beamer template, and I have most of the things the CD requires done, but I can't seem to be able to influence how the TOC looks like.

This is how it is supposed to look like:

[image: TOC formatting]

(But the LaTeX-Beamer version should have enumeration, rather than bullets.)

I tried `\setbeamercolor{section in toc}` and its subsections but that changes the colour of both the text and the enumeration.

**Most importantly, I have no clue how to get the grey box done.**